# If $X$ is regular and $C\subset X$ is compact

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is regular and $C\subset X$ is compact, and $x\notin C$, then there are open sets $U,V$ such that $x\in U$, $C\subset V$, and $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

My attempt:

Suppose for a contradiction, there do not exist such $U $ and $V$. Let $\{U_i\mid i\in I\}$ be an open cover of $C$, by compactness, let $\{U_1,..,U_n\}$ be a finite subcover. Then $C\subset U_1\cup...\cup U_n$.

Hence $\cup_{i\leq n}{U_i}$ is an open set containing $C$, and $X\setminus\cup_{i\leq n}{U_i}$ is a closed set.

Either $x\in\cup_{i\leq n}{U_i}$ or $x\notin\cup_{i\leq n}{U_i}$.

If $x\notin\cup_{i\leq n}{U_i}$, then $x\in X\setminus\cup_{i\leq n}{U_i}$.

For each $y\in C$, $y\notin X\setminus\cup_{i\leq n}{U_i}$.

For each $i\leq n$, let $V_{y_i}, W_{y_i}$ be such that $X\setminus\cup_{i\leq n}{U_i}\subseteq V_{y_i}$, $y_i\in U_i\subseteq W_{y_i}$, and $V_{y_i}\cap W_{y_i}=\emptyset$. We can pick such $V_{y_i}, W_{y_i}$ since $X$ is regular.

Let $V:=\cap_{i\leq n}{V_{y_i}}$ and $W:=\cup_{i\leq n}{W_{y_i}}$. Then both $V$ and $W$ are open and disjoint, $x\in V$, $C\subset W$, which contradicts our assumption.

But where is the contradiction for when $x\in\cup_{i\leq n}{U_i}$?

Alternatively, it suffices to show that $x$ has a neighborhood which does not intersect with $C$.

Suppose for a contradiction, every neighborhood of $x$ intersects with $C$. Let $\{U_i\mid i\in I\}$ be the set of all open neighborhoods of $x$. Then $U_i\cap C\neq\emptyset$ for each $i\in I$. But I'm not sure how to proceed from here?

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble following your proof. How are you able to find $W_{y_i}$ such that it contains $U_i$ using regularity?

Comment: Yeah I see that. It's probably flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your definition of regular includes Hausdorff, for otherwise the claim is wrong. Indeed, consider the set $X:=\{x,y\}$ with the trivial topology, and denote $C:=\{y\}$. Then $X$ is regular, $C$ is compact, $x\not\in C$, and there are no nonempty disjoint subsets of $X$.

Now, with the assumption that $X$ is Hausdorff, we find that $C$ must be closed as it is a compact subspace of a Hausdorff space. Then the claim follows by regularity.